# Show UserControl in tabitem of tabcontrol

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls, tabcontrol

I want to open User Controls in `TabItem`s of a `TabControl`.

I am doing this in this way :

```
    <Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:a="clr-namespace:Pauspan_WPF_"
    Title="Pauspan" Height="568" Width="1095" Name="FrmMain">
    <Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <TabControl Height="400" Margin="187,33,16,0" Name="TbCtrlMain" >
        <TabItem Header="TabItem1" Name="TabItem1">
            <a:UserControl1 />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

but it gives an error on this line:

```
    <a:usercontrol1/>
```

The error is :

```
  **The type 'a:UserControl1' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.**
```

Usercontrol1 in the name of UserControl.

How can I do this? Why does this error come about?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32825/How-to-Creating-a-WPF-User-Control-using-it-in-a-W

Comment: are you sure UserControl1 is in Pauspan_WPF_ namespace of same assembly?

Comment: I do not know how to check it ?? or how to add it in assembly ???

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and although the designer complains and shows errors, it still lets me compile the project. I just left the ";assembly=...." bit out of my xaml.

```
<Window x:Class="SafeDrivingCertificate.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:rt="clr-namespace:SafeDrivingCertificate"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="tc" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TabItem Header="Review Coming Due" Name="tbReview">
                <rt:ReviewTab />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `ContentTemplate` of your `TabControl`?  See this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.contenttemplate.aspx

You can set the `ContentTemplate` to a `DataTemplate` that uses your UserControl1.